# Sapper Svelte Routes not working and Pages missing when Deployed to Netlify

Tags: routes, svelte, netlify, sapper

I have seen others ask this question but no other answers seem to help.

I have a basic svelte / sapper application that has a Nav Bar component.

Locally, the navbar and website functions perfectly, however, when deploying to netlify ( and using `npm run dev` and `__sapper__/export` ), I get a few issues...

1. First issue is that my ChartJS charts won't load. Maybe that is for another question, but might be relevant
2. When clicking on a nav link, the url changes to the proper URL within my browser, but the page does not load. However, after clicking a nav link and seeing the URl appear in the browser search bar, I can just reloading the page and the desired page will load( but again, without any chartJS charts ), but, it adds a "/" to the end of the route ( which it doesn't do locally ).
3. When trying to visit a route not in the navbar, I get a "Page not found" error, despite it appearing locally.

I have deployed a sapper site before, using the same commands, but for some reason, this site will not work.

The only relevant code would be my `_layout.svelte` which holds my NavBar, so it appears across all screens. Similar to the default layout in something like Vue I believe.

```js
    import Nav from '../components/Nav.svelte';
```

```html
<style>

</style>

<Nav/>
<main>
    <slot></slot>
</main>
```

I can't seem to find any fixes, at least ones that have worked for me.

What is very confusing to me is why one of my routes gives the "page not found" error, despite the route existing. Why would ONLY that route not appear on netlify, and not other routes I directly route to from the Browser Search bar.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: I have the same problem with browsers under iOS. 
My app is built, not exported.
Regular desktop and Android - are OK.
still searching for the answer ((

Answer (score 3):

The sapper export scripts works by starting at an entry point (usually `index.svelte`) and "clicking" on all visible links to crawl like that to all the pages.  It will render each page it visited as a separate .html file, which can be served directly by your host (Netlify in this case).

What this means is that *each* that is **not** directly accessible by clicking on a displayed link will **not** be exported, this causes some o your problems:

#### 404 page / Other pages

I suppose you do not link directly to your 404 page do you ? :)
You can tell sapper to start at several end points by specifying them in your export command

```
"export": "sapper export --entry "/ /404"",
```

Since it only clicks *displayed links* there are also 2 other common problems

- buttons that act as links
- links hidden behind a button (hamburger menus for instance)

Solving the first one is easy: if it's a link it should be a link, don't use buttons for links, you can always style your link to look like a button

(this one might not apply to you, because it seems your pages are exported, just adding if for future readers)
The second one is a bit more work, but it usually is solved by adding an invisible list of links available in your navigation somewhere in your markup.

```html
<nav>
  {#if navigationOpen}
    <a href="">...</a>
  {/if}
  <div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute">
    <a href="">...</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In the example above I duplicated the menu in a hidden section, this can be picked up by sapper, personally I keep it with the nav, so I don't forget to change links when I change the nav, but you could as well put this div on your index page. (An alternative is to have visible links to each section on your landing page!)

#### ChartJS not loading

I think this might be another question, what you can do is export locally and check if your ChartJs script is correctly copied from the statics folder. Also check if the path to the script is correct, it is best to prepend all paths to static files with a / in the template to ensure the browser looks for them from the root url.

```html
<!-- on page myhost.com/page/blob -->
<!-- points to myhost.com/page/blob/library.js -->
<script src="library.js"></script>
<!-- points to myhost.com/library.js -->
<script src="/library.js"></script>
```

#### Not navigating

I have not heard of or seen this before, but it might be related to the previous points, you can always export locally and serve the site locally to see if it's not a configuration issue on netlify ?

Comment: Thanks for your response Stephane. The 404 on my non visible link makes sense. I actually do not like this idea, because I do not want one of those routes to be visible on the home page. Like you said, there are work around, but I might just go back to svelte and just add routing. I am still confused on why “clicking a nav link” will “load” the url path in my browser, but won’t actually direct me to that page. I’ll see if fixing the first issues will fix those issues. Is there a way to host the sapper site without exporting / using separate .htmls ？

Comment: The not loading of the url is strange, you can host a sapper site without exporting on any node server.

Comment: I am new to deploying sites. I mainly use netlify. The site works perfect locally. I am sorry for my lack of knowledge here. It is so weird. I go to my site and no nav links work. if i refresh, it will go to the page of the last nav linked clinked. Only then, can i navigate throughout my app normally. Can I PM you a link to the site so you can see?

Comment: @ETHan Did you end figuring this out? Having the exact same problem.

Comment: @Casimir no I actually ended up going with routify.dev instead for my routing solution ( which I enjoy and would recommend ).